# Factorization of GCD

Tags: divisibility, prime-factorization

I'm working on a question about factorization of a GCD.

Let x = p$^{n1}_1$ ... p$^{nk}_k$

Is it correct to answer this with: p$^{n1}_1$ + $^{m1}_1$ ... p$^{nk}_k$ + $^{mk}_k$ ?

Comment: By $p_1^{n1}+_1^{m1}$ do you mean $p_1^{(n_1+m_1)}$?  That is how I am taking it.

Comment: Yes I do, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, try $x=12=2^2\cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0, y=1350=2^1\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2$.  The GCD is not $2^3\cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2=16200$  For a common divisor, you need the minimum of the exponents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so how do I formulate this if I want to get the minimum?

Comment: You just want $\min(n_1,m_1)$ etc.

Comment: So p$^{min(n1, m1)}_1$ ... p$^{min(nk, mk)}_k$ would be the answer then?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!